# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I have the next mistake, why happen this?. This is the trace. I'm working with webservices to attack a mysql database

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing
org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2470)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.consultarCuentas(WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.java:753)
es.uniway.action.cuentas.CuentasAction.execute(CuentasAction.java:50)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)


causa raíz 

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArrayDeserializer.characters(ArrayDeserializer.java:502)
org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.characters(DeserializationContext.java:966)
org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:177)
org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.consultarCuentas(WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.java:753)
es.uniway.action.cuentas.CuentasAction.execute(CuentasAction.java:50)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario de Apache Tomcat/7.0.12.

And the method from the ws which provokes this is this:

```
public String[][] consultarCuentas(int id_tipo_cuenta){  //Acabar método para login

    String [][] params = null; 

    try {
        this.conexion=conectar();
        System.out.println("Vamos a usar el id tipo cuenta:"+id_tipo_cuenta);
        int id_tipo_cuenta_padre=id_tipo_cuenta-1;

        SQL="SELECT t1.id_cuenta                                             as id_cuenta,"+     
                "t1.n_cuenta                                              as n_cuenta,"+
           "SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.n_cuenta,'.',"+id_tipo_cuenta_padre+")                       as n_cuenta_padre,"+
           "t1.nombre_cuenta                                         as nombre,"+         
           "(SELECT tt1.cif"+
           "  FROM cuentas_rs tt1"+
            " WHERE tt1.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+
            " ORDER BY tt1.f_inicio DESC "+
            " LIMIT 1)                                                as cif,"+                          
            "(SELECT tt2.porcentaje "+
            " FROM impuestos tt2"+
            " WHERE tt2.id_pais = (SELECT tt1.cif"+
            "                     FROM cuentas_rs tt1"+
            "                     WHERE tt1.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+
            "                     ORDER BY tt1.f_inicio DESC"+
            "                     LIMIT 1)"+
            " ORDER BY tt2.f_inicio DESC "+
            "LIMIT 1)                                                as impuesto,"+
           "t1.descuento                                             as descuento,"+      
           "t1.id_tipo_cuenta                                        as nivel,"+          
           "t1.borrado                                               as borrado,"+        
           "t1.cod_cliente                                           as cod_cliente "+     
           "FROM cuentas t1 "+
           "LEFT OUTER JOIN cuentas_rs t2 ON t2.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+ 
           " WHERE t1.id_esquema_asociado = 1"+  
           " AND t1.id_proveedor_cloud = 1"+
           " AND SUBSTRING(t1.n_cuenta,1,LENGTH(001.00001))"+
           " AND t1.id_tipo_cuenta =("+id_tipo_cuenta+")"+
           " AND t1.borrado = false"+         
           " AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE '%'" +         
           " ORDER BY t1.nombre_cuenta ASC";

        this.stm    = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);


        this.rs =  this.pstm.executeQuery();

        this.rs.last(); 
        int numRows = this.rs.getRow(); 
        this.rs.beforeFirst();
        System.out.println("Vamos a hacer:"+numRows);
        params = new String[numRows][10];

        int i=0;
         while(this.rs.next()){

                params[i][0]=String.valueOf(this.rs.getInt("id_cuenta"));
                params[i][1]=this.rs.getString("n_cuenta");
                params[i][2]=this.rs.getString("n_cuenta_padre");
                params[i][3]=this.rs.getString("nombre");
                params[i][4]=this.rs.getString("cif");
                params[i][5]=String.valueOf(this.rs.getDouble("impuesto"));
                params[i][6]=String.valueOf(this.rs.getDouble("descuento"));
                params[i][7]=String.valueOf(this.rs.getInt("nivel"));
                params[i][8]=String.valueOf(this.rs.getBoolean("borrado"));
                params[i][9]=this.rs.getString("cod_cliente");

            i++;        

            }
         return params;  
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return params;  

}
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to generate the web service using document/literal but not with document/literal(wrapped).This will solve your problem.